# What's the difference between libc6-i386 and libc6:i386?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Have ubuntu 14.10 and 15.04, both 64bit. Have to do some 32bit development, so I've installed `gcc-multiarch` and `g++-multiarch`. Simple `Hello World` c++ code works for all -m64, -m32 and -mx32 ABIs. But I was surprised that what I have installed is `libc6-i386` and corresponding `dev` libs. Because when I'm trying to install `libmpfr-dev:i386` (or any other `:i386` dev libs) `apt` is pulling whole set of libc/gcc/g++/libstdc++ libraries with `:i386` postfix. Could someone shed a light why I ought to have another libc6 and another gcc for 32bit development? How it is supposed to work together with multiarch?